# Regex for city and street name

Tags: regex, validation, expression

Hi, I am looking for 2 regex which describe:

1) a valid name of a street

2) a valid name of a city

**Valid street names are:**

- Mainstreet.
- Mainstreet
- Main Street
- Big New mainstreet
- Mainstreet-New
- Mains Str.
- St. Alexander Street
- abcÜüßäÄöÖàâäèéêëîï ôœùûüÿçÀÂ-ÄÈÉÊËÎÏÔŒÙÛÜŸÇ.
- John Kennedy Street

**Not valid street names are:**

- Mainstreet #+;:_*´`?=)(/&%$§!
- Mainstreet#+;:_*´`?=)(/&%$§!
- Mainstreet 2
- Mainstreet..
- Mainstreet§

**Valid cities are:**

- Edinôœùûüÿ
- Berlin.
- St. Petersburg
- New-Berlin
- Aue-Bad Schlema
- Frankfurt am Main
- Nürnberg
- Ab
- New York CityßäÄöÖàâäèéêëîïôœùûüÿçÀÂ-ÄÈÉÊËÎÏÔŒÙÛÜŸ

**Not valid cities are:**

- Edingburgh 123
- Edingburg123
- St. Andrews 12
- Berlin,#+;:_*´`?=)(/&%$§!
- Berlin__

The solutions that I have at the moment matches very close but not perfectly:

For city and street name:

```
^[^\W\d_]+(?:[-\s][^\W\d_]+)*[.]?$
```

Unfortunately no match for these examples (the rest works fine):

- St. Alexander Street
- St. Petersburg

If you have more simple solutions, I am happy to learn sth. new! :-)

Comment: This sounds like a really bad idea. Never underestimate the crazy variety of names people will give things - street names with numbers in, for instance, are actually rather common.

Comment: [Westward Ho!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Westward_Ho!) (named after the book) would have a problem with the exclusion of "!".

Comment: Be prepared to still get `Frankfurt (Main)` and `Heide (Holst)`, just like the train company uses to distinguish cities. Also you don't seem to expect `Øresund`, `Москва`, `Θεσσαλονίκη`, `İstanbul` and `東京`. Streets and house numbers are sometimes not enough: addendums like `Hof 5` or `Eingang 3` may be needed for further distinction.

Comment: Very good point! How can add ``Frankfurt (Main)``?
True, I am actually excpecting only names from Germany. I have included some exotic characters just to be sure.  However, if there is a simple way to add all these characters, this would be great

Comment: @PParker At some point, you have to define more clearly what you're trying to _prevent_. What do you expect to gain by trying to whitelist every possible name?

Comment: True! Sorry for that. I think the only think missing for me is ```Frankfurt (Main)```. The other thinks are not crucial!!!

Comment: ...until someone comes and writes `Frankfurt/Main`. You even have to expect things like `D0RTMUND` (`0` instead of `O`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it match `St. Alexander Street` and `St. Petersburg`, you just need to add an optional dot after the letter matching patterns:

```
^[^\W\d_]+\.?(?:[-\s][^\W\d_]+\.?)*$
#         ^^^                 ^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FpwyN6/1).

Also, it might make sense to add a single apostrophe to the regex:

```
^[^\W\d_]+\.?(?:[-\s'’][^\W\d_]+\.?)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FpwyN6/2).

Comment: What can I do to match ``Frankfurt (Main)`` as well?

Comment: @PParker `^\(?[^\W\d_]+\.?\)?(?:[-\s]\(?[^\W\d_]+\.?\)?)*$`

Comment: Hopefully one last question: Your suggestions to match ``Frankfurt (Main)`` works, but then it also matches ``New York)``, which is wrong